# PHP mail() NOT working on Windows (IIS)

Tags: php, windows, email, iis

Below is my source using the PHP mail function

```
$to = "you@domain.com";
$subject = "This is the subject line
$message = "This is the message"
$headers = 'From: no-reply@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: admin@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$result = mail($to , $subject , $message, $headers )
```

Below is my PHP config, which is running on Windows IIS

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com
```

Comment: Going by your config you should have a mail service or exchange running on the same IIS environment. Can you confirm that this is true? If its not then you need to specify a mail server, otherwise you should debug the mail() function to see what it is returning :)

Comment: I would guess that the syntax highlighting performed by StackOverflow directly in your question is a good starting point.

Comment: @MonkeyZues does have a fair point, You are missing a "; and ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send mail you should [configure smtp](http://www.vsysad.com/2012/04/setup-and-configure-smtp-server-on-windows-server-2008-r2/). IIS its just web server.

Comment: And where does it suggest that he has not configured his config correctly? IIS and Exchange(or other mail service) can exist on the same machine.

Comment: @NeilMasters Well does IIS send emails?

Comment: @NeilMasters more info in config smtp is reffering to localhost:25 thats why here my suggestion came

Comment: Absolutely not, some IIS Services are required on Windows 10 in order for the send_mail function to work, it has an inbuilt mail server.

Comment: @Towelie This answer is 7 years old lots of stuff changed since yhen